# Errors using UITextField and UITextView

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, uitextfield, uitextview

I  am adding to my Xcode project a text field which displays text in a text view. I have got mostly the coding for it to work, but it throws back two errors. The first one is

> Cannot assign value of type '(UITextField) -> (UITextRange) -> String?' to type 'String?

This is after `textView.text = mText` in the enter button function. The second error is

> Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String?' and '(UITextField) -> (UITextRange) -> String?'

after the `textView.text += mText` line. How can these problems be resolved?

```
import UIKit

class ShowGratitudeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    @IBAction func enterTextButton(_ sender: Any) {

        //gets text from text field
        let mText = UITextField.text

        //update previous text of textview
        textView.text = mText
    }

    @IBAction func editTextButton(_ sender: Any) {

        //gets text from text field
        let mText = UITextField.text

        //add text after previous text
        textView.text += mText
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mistyped `textField` with `UITextField`. `UITextField` is a class and you can not get the text of the `textField` object from it.

Another error you have is `+=` can not apply on an optional and a non-optional values. So unwrap it before applying this operator.

So the code would be like:

```
class ShowGratitudeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    @IBAction func enterTextButton(_ sender: Any) {

        //gets text from text field
        let mText = textField.text

        //update previous text of textview
        textView.text = mText
    }

    @IBAction func editTextButton(_ sender: Any) {

        //gets text from text field
        let mText = textField.text

        //add text after previous text
        textView.text! += mText!
    }
}
```

Comment: unwrap `mText` as well like `textView.text! += mText!`

Comment: Eagle eye. Thanks @Kamran